# Acessar variaveis de outra classe swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, classes, variáveis

Tenho uma classe `Main` em minha aplicação, e nela tenho criada a variável `cod` que recebe o valor de `0`, nessa classe também tenho uma seqüência de botões que neles contém o evento de alterar o valor de `cod` para, `1`, `2` ou `3`, e clicando após o *click* no botão, a aplicação é alterada para um outro *layout*. Nesse outro *layout*, correspondido por outra classe chamada `Resultado`, preciso acessar o valor de `cod`, mas quando utilizo o `var dados = Main().cod`, ele me retorna o valor de `0`, ou seja.. por mais que os botões tenham o `cod = 1`, a variável não está sendo alterada:

```
class Main: UIViewController {
    var cod = 0

    @IBAction func btnSp(sender: AnyObject) {
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewConsultas") as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

        cod = 1
    }
}
```

e na classe resultado

```
    var dados = Main().cod
```

o que estou fazendo errado que não consigo acessar o valor alterado de `cod`?

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que ao fazer `Main()` você está criando uma nova instância desta classe, então o valor da variável `cod` é o inicial, que é **0**.

O ideal é você passar esse valor através da `ViewController` que você chama, passando assim do "pai para o filho".

Supondo que sua segunda classe é um `ResultadoViewController` e esteja mais ou menos assim:

```
class ResultadoViewController: UIViewController {
    var cod: Int!
}
```

Então, a chamada do seu botão pode ficar assim:

```
@IBAction func btnSp(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let resultadoController: ResultadoViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewConsultas") as ResultadoViewController

    resultadoController.cod = 1

    presentViewController(resultadoController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```